# Using Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am having soon issues using the twitter bootstrap modal in my site. My site has the has bootstrap loaded and everything but the button is not trigger the popup and I don't know why. Can someone please help me?

This is the modal right after my body tag

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnshow").on('click', function(event) {

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
      // do more here
    })

  });

});
```

sample button that calls your modal window

```
<button id="btnshow">Show</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootbox.js is a small JavaScript library which allows you to create programmatic dialog boxes using Bootstrap modals, without having to worry about creating, managing or removing any of the required DOM elements or JS event handlers. Here’s the simplest possible example:

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

```
bootbox.dialog({
title: "That html",
message: '<img src="images/bootstrap_logo.png" width="100px"/><br/> You can also use <b>html</b>'
});
```